# How to use JavaScript variables loaded from an external library with Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a Next.js with Typescript site that I'm trying to install ads on. The advertising provider provided instructions to include this Javascript on my website:

```js
<script src="//m.servedby-buysellads.com/monetization.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  (function(){
    if(typeof _bsa !== 'undefined' && _bsa) {
      _bsa.init('flexbar', 'MYTOKEN', 'placement:wwwmysitecom');
    }
  })();
</script>
```

The library loads a file like `var _bsa={init:function(format...`. So in my main **pages/_app.tsx** file, I include the script and snippet like:

```
  if(typeof _bsa !== 'undefined' && _bsa) {
    _bsa.init('flexbar', 'MYTOKEN', 'placement:wwwmysitecom');
  } else {
    console.log("bsa is undefined")
  } 

  return (
    <>
      <Script src="//m.servedby-buysellads.com/monetization.js" type="text/javascript"></Script>
```

When I load the page for the first time, I get the log message "bsa is undefined". How can I call this `_bsa.init` function after the `monetization.js` library loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `undefined` because the browser should make a request to get the JavaScript file. And by default, Next.js loads the script early but after some hydration on the page occurs. So a solution here is to use the [`onLoad`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script#onload) function of `Script`, like so:

```js
<Script
  onLoad={() => {
    _bsa.init("flexbar", "MYTOKEN", "placement:wwwmysitecom");
    console.log(_bsa);
  }}
  src="//m.servedby-buysellads.com/monetization.js"
  type="text/javascript"
/>
```

There is also [`onReady`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script#onready) if you want it to fire on load and after each render.